# Schedule task after certain time when another task finishes execution

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring framework based application.

I have a requirement in which when user logs in to the system, then after certain time gap say 2 minutes or 5 minutes(which should be configurable), another task will start its execution. After that execution completed, result will be published on UI.

So, can anyone tell me the way to implement this in Spring framework.

Comment: spring AOP+timertasks can possibly provide and solution

Comment: Can you please elaborate which API can help me?

Comment: You can try creating a scheduled timertask after user login, can refer here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html setting some time x mins after current time etc etc.

Comment: there are many options refer the links and suit yourself

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/scheduling.html 
 ;; http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/beans-spring/spring-3-scheduler-example-jdk-timer-and-quartz-showcase/
  ;;  http://www.javabeat.net/spring-job-scheduling-support-with-jdk-timer-and-quartz/  ;;  perform some poc first then i believe you can easily get your job done

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a specific way to do it in Spring.
I usually exploit the JAVA SE 7 interface [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)
There are a lot of samples on the web.
One of them is [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54).